# html and css form tag positioning

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am trying to create a form for registering users with a centered horizontal and vertical position.  I have multiple input fields for obvious reasons followed by a submit button.  I also have the page divided up into 3 sections, a header, a main body, and a footer.

I seemed to have gotten it horizontally but cannot figure it out vertically.

```
<div id="main-background">
        <div id="main">
            <form name="registration" id="registration">
                <input id="first-name" type="text" name="first-name" placeholder="First Name" size="15">
                <input id="last-name" type="text" name="last-name" placeholder="Last Name" size="15">
                <input id="date-of-birth" type="text" name="date-of-birth" placeholder="Date of Birth" size="15">
                <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" size="15">
                <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" size="15">
                <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" size="15">
                <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submit()">
            </form>
        </div><!-- main -->
    </div><!-- end of main-background -->

#main {
    background-color: #d9d9d9;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 800px;
    padding: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 990px;
}

#registration {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 0 auto;
}

#first-name {
    border-color:#cccccc; 
    border-style:solid; 
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0 auto;
    font-size:14px; 
    text-align: center; 
    border-width:1px; 
    border-radius:5px; 
}

#last-name {
    border-color:#cccccc; 
    border-style:solid; 
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0 auto;
    font-size:14px; 
    text-align: center;  
    border-width:1px; 
    border-radius:5px; 
}

#date-of-birth {
    border-color:#cccccc; 
    border-style:solid;
    display: block; 
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0 auto; 
    font-size:14px; 
    text-align: center;  
    border-width:1px; 
    border-radius:5px; 
}

#email {
    border-color:#cccccc; 
    border-style:solid; 
    display: block; 
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0 auto; 
    font-size:14px; 
    text-align: center;  
    border-width:1px; 
    border-radius:5px; 
}

#username {
    border-color:#cccccc; 
    border-style:solid;
    display: block;  
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0 auto; 
    font-size:14px; 
    text-align: center;  
    border-width:1px; 
    border-radius:5px; 
}

#password {
    border-color:#cccccc; 
    border-style:solid; 
    display: block; 
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0 auto;
    font-size:14px; 
    text-align: center;  
    border-width:1px; 
    border-radius:5px; 
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to center the form or the entire containing element (#main)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small change and a simple addition:

```
#registration {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto; // removed margin-top
}
```

Browswer support for `transform` is quite nice:

[Caniuse: transform2d](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)

Answer (score 0):

Did you want the form itself centered, or the elements within the form centered? I assumed you are asking for the former. In that case make the following changes:

```
#main {
    background-color: #d9d9d9;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 800px;
    padding: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 990px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

#registration {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

On `#registration` you need to use `margin` and not `margin-top`. You can then use `flexbox` to vertically center the form.